# Javascript is reading info about image on screen but manipulates original image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to crop an image that is being displayed on the screen but it does all of the changes to the original image even though it is returning the information about the resized image that is being displayed. So that when I get to context.drawImage() it's not using what it is reading!

My original image is 1040x980. When loaded on an iPad it gets scaled down to 823x776, for a scale of about 0.791.

The code that I posted below basically trims excess white space off of the canvas for a floor plan and then scales down all of the additional options so that they are placed in the correct spot on the scaled down floor plan.

```
    function getLeftEdge(myImage) {
        var direction = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
        var wsLeft = "";
        var wsRight = "";

        // Get original canvas size for scaling
        var canvasSize = document.getElementById("canvas_size").innerHTML;
        var tmp = canvasSize.split("x");
        var width = tmp[0];
        var height = tmp[1];
        var img = document.getElementById(myImage);

        // This returns 823x776
        console.log("Image is " + img.width +"x" + img.height);

        var scale = img.width/width;
        console.log("scaled to " + scale); // 0.7913461538461538

        // Get white space values for trimming the canvas
        var whiteSpace = document.getElementById("white_space").innerHTML;
        console.log("white space is " + whiteSpace); // 383,363
        var tmp = whiteSpace.split(",");
        if (direction == "R")
        {
            wsLeft = parseInt(tmp[1]);
            wsRight = parseInt(tmp[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            wsLeft = parseInt(tmp[0]);
            wsRight = parseInt(tmp[1]);
        }

        // get the additional space needed for the left side
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    if (req.status == 200) {

                        var addSpace = req.responseText.split(",");
                        if (direction == "R")
                        {
                            var addSpaceLeft = parseInt(addSpace[1]) * scale;
                            var addSpaceRight = parseInt(addSpace[0]) * scale;
                        } else {
                            var addSpaceLeft = parseInt(addSpace[0]) * scale;
                            var addSpaceRight = parseInt(addSpace[1]) * scale;
                        }
                        console.log("additional left side space needed is " + addSpaceLeft); // 91.79615384615384
                        wsLeft = wsLeft * scale - addSpaceLeft;
                        wsRight = wsRight * scale - addSpaceRight;

                        // Replace the base image with the scaled and trimmed image
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.width = img.width - wsLeft - wsRight;
                        canvas.height = img.height;
                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        console.log("Draw image start at " + wsLeft + "," + 0); // 211.28942307692307,0
                        console.log("Clip x for " + canvas.width + " pixels"); // 324
                        console.log("Make the final image " + canvas.width +"x" + canvas.height); // 324x614

                        // ****** here is the problem!!!
                        context.drawImage(img, wsLeft, 0, canvas.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        $(img).replaceWith(canvas);

                        // We now want to apply scale to left, top, height, and width of the option images

                        var left = 0;
                        var dir = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
                        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('FPimage');
                        for(var i=0, l=elements.length; i<l; i++){
                            if (dir == "R")
                            {
                                var position = parseInt(elements[i].getAttribute('data-left')); 
                                position = (position - wsRight) * scale;
                                elements[i].style.right = position + "px";
                            } else {
                                left = parseInt(elements[i].getAttribute('data-left')) - wsLeft;
                                elements[i].style.left = left * scale + "px";
                            }
                            elements[i].style.top = elements[i].getAttribute('data-top') * scale + "px";
                            elements[i].style.height = elements[i].getAttribute('data-height') * scale + "px";
                            elements[i].style.width = elements[i].getAttribute('data-width') * scale + "px";
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("GET", "leftAdj.asp?ProductID=" + getProductID() + "&wsLeft=" + wsLeft + "&wsRight=" + wsRight + "&currentLevel=" + getLevel() + "&canvasWidth=" + width, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
```

Here is what I am getting -

[image]

If it were working on the 823x776 image this is what it would return -

[image]

My question is why is it not using the image that it sees as 823x776? I hope this isn't too confusing.

Edit:

Sorry, forgot to mention that this function is called at the end of window.onload(). So it first reads what the device has scaled the image to on it's own. Which is where 823x776 comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that even though the browser reports that it has an image of size 823x776 it's really just giving the size being displayed. When working on the image I needed to use math for the full scale image and then just scale down the image when using drawImage

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    width = width - wsLeft - wsRight;
    canvas.width = width * scale;
    canvas.height = height * scale;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, wsLeft, 0, width, height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    $(img).replaceWith(canvas);
```